# SharePoint Workflow Reminder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-email

I am receiving an email reminder from somewhere in SharePoint (I think) regards to a particular list in SharePoint 2013, I have checked the list and there is no Workflow designed or configured for that particular list. the email is coming from [image]

I have opened the list with SharePoint designer and there is nothing there too, where would be other location that I need to check?
Regards

Comment: sometime types of workflow do not show up in Sharepoint Designer under the List.  In the menu on the left of the screen, try clicking on 'Workflows' and looks in there for other workflows.  It could be a 'reusable' workflow, these types of workflow don't show up in the List settings either.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I have checked that and still can not see any WF related to this list, there are many other Work Flow's for other sites.

Comment: What content in the email body and subject? could you share them? Also check if there are PowerShell cmdlets or Event Receivers associated with the list.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the workflow might actually be attached to a content type, rather than the list instance?  You can check this directly from your affected list by going to List Settings > Workflow Settings.  Then click the dropdown "Show workflow associations of this type" (which defaults to 'This List'), and see if there is anything else listed there.

Alternatively you could check whether you have an alert setup - go to the affected list again and click the List tab in the ribbon.  Then click "Alert Me", and then click "Manage My Alerts".  This should show if you have an alert setup.  Note, if you don't see the "Alert Me" button then alerts are not setup for your site.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have checked both Alerts section and Show workflow associations of this type and there was no WF, the thing is is this notification coming from this list I should see the list name in From section in the email, however in From section I can see the email sender name twice, as screenshot I have provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Are your list a Issue Tracking or Tasks list? For these 2 list type, there is E-Mail Notification setting. It is a built-in feature, no workflow is associated.

Open your list -> List Settings -> Advanced settings. Check the **E-Mail Notification** section, you can switch Yes/No for **Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?**